# Tree vs Regression algorithm- which works better for a model with mostly categorical features?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, random-forest, decision-tree

I'm working on a regression problem to predict the selling price of a product. The features are a 4-level product hierarchy and a proposed price. In summary, there are 4 categorical features and one numerical feature. There are about 1000K rows in total.

I think a decision tree or random forest would work better than regression in this scenario. The reasoning is that there is only one numerical feature. Also, I plan to convert the numerical feature (proposed price) into price buckets, making it another categorical feature.

Does my reasoning make sense? Is there any other algorithm that might be worthy to try? Is there any other clever feature engineering that is worthy trying?

Note 1: This is actually a challenge problem (like Kaggle), so the features have been masked and encoded. Looking at the data, I can say for sure that there is a 4-level product hierarchy, but I'm not very sure about the one numerical feature (which I think is the proposed price), because there is a lot of difference in some scenarios between this number and the sold price (y variable). Also, there are a lot of outliers (probably forcibly introduced to confuse) in this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend binning the proposed price variable, as one would expect that variable to carry most information needed to predict the selling price. Binning that variable is advantageous when the variable is noisy, however it comes at a cost since you throw away valuable information. You do not have to bin your continuous variable, Trees will do it for you (and RFs likewise). If your categorical variables are ordinal you do not have to do anything, however if they are not you may consider encoding the variables (map the distinct values to let's say one hot vectors -- 0,0,1) and try other regressors that way, such as SVR from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html (in this case you may consider scaling the variables to [0,1]).

edit: RFs are better than trees in general just make sure you know what you're doing. And make sure you understand that RFs are many trees ensembled together.

Comment: Thanks. I have added Note 1 to clarify why I think about binning the proposed price.